# Installing two different versions of the same dependency on virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Previously everything was working fine until today that i have started getting this message

```
  PyJWT>=2.0.0 (from social-auth-core==4.0.3->social-auth-app-django==4.0.0->-r requirements.in (line 8))
  pyjwt<2.0.0 (from snowflake-connector-python==2.3.9->-r requirements.in (line 12))
```

The error is crystal clear, it seems that social-auth-core needs the pyJWT version newer than 2.0.0 and snowflake-connector-python need an older version.

I don't know if someone else run into something similar and what is the solution in this case.

The issue is that we are using auth0 to login into the app and snowflake to run some queries so we cannot let off one of those dependencies.

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for an answer the solution was to find an older version of the two libraries where they can use the same version of PyJWT.